# The return code from 'grep' is not as expected on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm struggling to see why the following is returning a code of 1.

```
echo 'Total' | grep -c No
0
```

So "No" doesn't exists in "Total". But then looking up its return code I'm seeing it as 1.

```
echo $?
1
```

Why is return code showing up as 1? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: `grep` will return zero only when some string is matched.  this rule is applicable for `grep -c` as well.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

According to `man grep` page, `-c` flag is for

> -c, --count
>                 Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.

So what you are seeing is the count of the match and not to be confused with the exit code of the `grep` match. The code `1` is because of no lines matching from the input.

Have a look at the other case,

```
echo 'No' | grep -c No
1

echo $?
0
```

Also to read on `EXIT CODES` on `man grep` page,

> EXIT STATUS
>          Normally  the  exit  status  is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.

Comment: You will have to remove the `-e` from  the bash Shebang `#!/bin/bash -e` 
 comment, otherwise the grep exit 1 status will still cause your script to exit.

Answer (score 62):

The exit code is 1 because nothing was matched by grep.

> EXIT STATUS
>         The  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.
>         If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling
>         code should check for '2' or greater.)

The output is zero because the count of 'Total' is zero. This due to the -c option:

> -c, --count
>                 Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
>                 for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
>                 below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)

If you would like to force an exit code of 0, you can just append `|| true` to your command:

```
echo 'Total' | grep -c No || true
```

Comment: Alternatively, `|| :` also seems to work in bash.